# Spectral theory of Bochner integral operators

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Consider the following (somewhat simplified) situation. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be separable Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators acting on $\mathcal{H}$. Let further $J:[0,1]\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be continuous mapping with values in self-adjoint bounded operators. So one can define
$$I(J):=\int_{0}^{1}J(t)dt$$
as the Bochner integral.

My question is a bit vague but I would like to know something like this: What can be said about the spectral properties of operator $I(J)$ if we know the spectral resolution of $J(t)$ for $\forall t\in[0,1]$?

A more concrete example of questions, I am interested in, is the following: If $\sigma_{ess}(J(t))=[a(t),b(t)]$ for $\forall t\in[0,1]$, is then true that 
$$\sigma_{ess}(I(J))=[\inf_{t\in[0,1]}a(t),\sup_{t\in[0,1]}b(t)],$$
as one could expect "by integration"?

Do you know some literature devoted to this topic?

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: The equality is certainly false. Take $J$ such that $J(1-t)=-J(t)$, then $I(J)=0_{\mathcal H}$ and the essential spectrum is $\{0\}$. Only the inclusion could make sense.

Comment: It is important whether the operators commute with each other or not. If they do, one can apply the spectral theorem and represent them simultaneously as integrals over spectral projections. Then the Bochner integral should commute with the spectral integral, which means that you have to integrate spectral projections.